# iOS: How to alter an image on screenshot (Xcode 6.4, Swift 1.2)

Tags: ios, image, screenshot

Sorry if the question sounds noonish, but I couldn't find a clear answer to this: I know it is not possible to prevent a screenshot in iOS, so I was wondering if there is a way to graphically render an image that would make it look different if it was screenshotted. Now I am not asking for a full technical explanation, but I would like to have a pointer in the good direction, like if there is a specific technical term (I looked into watermarking and steganography but didn't really find what I was looking for).

For instance I was thinking about using a filter in-app, but I assume it could also be captured by the screenshot, so I don't really know where to look.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking if you can alter an image graphically when someone tries to take a screenshot of it from their computer?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't precise: I mean from their iPhone.

Comment: I think the issue still stands. To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to control when or how someone takes a screenshot from their side of things.

Comment: Yeah so what I would like to do is do something on the images, that is invisible in-app but appears on the screenshot.